# Mysql query performance improvement for inventory calculation

Tags: mysql

*I have a database structure like this:*

*Table: `purchase_items`:*

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(110)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| purchase_id         | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id          | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| units               | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*Table: `sales_items`:*

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sales_id              | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| purchase_item_id      | bigint(100)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| qty                   | varchar(55)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*There is a `sales_return_items` table similar to `sales_items`*

I used to get the inventory as following:

```
SELECT
    pi.id,
    pi.product_id,
    pi.units,
    (
        SELECT SUM(si.qty) FROM sales_items si WHERE si.purchase_item_id = pi.id
    ) as sales_qty,
    (
        SELECT SUM(sri.qty) FROM sales_return_items sri WHERE sri.purchase_item_id = pi.id
    ) as sales_return_qty
FROM purchase_items pi
```

Above query used to get me the desired results.

But after adding a little more data error showing "request timeout" or taking more than 10 minutes to load the page.

**My question is:** How can I improve this query for performance?

Comment: Please do **not** change your initial question.  Stack Overflow questions are not blogs where you keep asking follow ups.  If you need help with a _different_ query, then ask a new question `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the correlated subqueries to joins:

```sql
SELECT
    pi.id,
    pi.product_id,
    pi.units,
    COALESCE(si.qty, 0) AS sales_qty,
    COALESCE(sri.qty, 0) AS sales_return_qty
FROM purchase_items pi
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT purchase_item_id, SUM(qty) AS qty 
    FROM sales_items
    GROUP BY purchase_item_id
) si
    ON si.purchase_item_id = pi.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT purchase_item_id, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM sales_return_items
    GROUP BY purchase_item_id
) sri
    ON sri.purchase_item_id = pi.id
GROUP BY
    pi.id;
```

Comment: Umm. `purchase_items` table has 111,705 items and `sales_items` table has 1,488,391 items. Would that be an issue?

Comment: Have you tried my code yet?

Comment: Create index for both tables with purchase_id....

Comment: @RahulBiswas Because the subqueries are finding the sum, adding an index may not help much.

Comment: Its working. Its now taking 10 seconds to load the data. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen outside the subquery it'll not help much but inside the subquery it will help.

Comment: No, I disagree.  The `GROUP BY` sum will likely be implemented using a hashmap and a full table scan.  Not much advantage to scanning an index, though it might help a small amount.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hello sir, I am having trouble for performance after adding another table to that list. Would would you please look into that. I have updated the question. Thanks for your help BTW.

Comment: I rolled back your edit.  Please read the comment directly under your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have tested your code with added 10000+ data in sales_return_items table. It doesn't return anything. Could you help